# Why when I upload an image the image styles are not shown for the first time?

Tags: 8, media

My settings are,

```
allow_insecure_derivatives: true
suppress_itok_output: false
```

Editing the itok token for the image src works at the browser level.

Does anyone know what causes the issue and a fix for it?

Notes :

1. When I hit CTRL+SHIFT+R in the browser the imagestyle images reappear. So the issues seems to be image is not present for the first time and browser is caching it.
2. The actual image can be accessed even for the first time without any issues. The issue is only with the image style images.
3. When I look at the actual image in the files folder, I see that there is an additional image with _0 attached to it. So looks like when the image is uploaded for the first time, it is assuming there is a duplicate and creating a new image. But still not sure why it would cause this issue.

Comment: your server does not have permission to write to the folder where you're trying to save it.

Comment: if you're on ubuntu, do this in your console go to your drupal default folder `cd /var/www/drupal/sites/default` and then `sudo chown www-data -R files`

Comment: I ve done this before(gave 777 to styles folder in /var/www/drupal/sites/default/files ) but still it seems broken..the image gets rendered but the browsers shows it as broken. when i remove or alter itok token image appears good.

Comment: For your `files` folder, what do you have as [owner/group](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HMLOi.jpg)?

Comment: www-data as owner and group

Comment: Does the uploaded image src point to the _0 image with the itok token or original image with the itok token?

Comment: It points to _0 image with itok token but the browser shows it as broken. but when i open the image link and alter the token the image renders perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same issue and as Russellt said, the issue was an extra space before a <?php tag.
There's a full thread about the issue here https://www.drupal.org/node/2195311

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/135258)

Answer (score 2):

Without access to the environment, it's going to be near impossible to know what's going on.

Something between the upload AJAX request, the image form element render, and the image style request, is causing the upload/render process to break. With that known, you can try debugging through key parts of this process to determine where key assumptions break:

1. [`file_managed_file_save_upload()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!file!file.module/function/file_managed_file_save_upload/8.2.x): Is the file being saved correctly at this point? Is there anything in the about the file system/configuration that creates a duplicate file?
2. [`ImageStyle::buildUrl()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!image!src!Entity!ImageStyle.php/function/ImageStyle%3A%3AbuildUrl/8.2.x): After the file is saved and the form element is being rendered, is the style URL being generated correctly? Is the token correct? Is the file used the same as the one previously saved?
3. [`ImageStyleDownloadController::deliver()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!image!src!Controller!ImageStyleDownloadController.php/function/ImageStyleDownloadController%3A%3Adeliver/8.2.x): Upon browser update, is the image payload delivery working correctly? Is this code being triggered (e.g. not proxied through some CDN)? Can it access the same file that was previously saved?

You can use [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) functions (e.g. `dpm(debug_backtrace())`), standard PHP debugging functions (e.g. `debug_print_backtrace()`), or whatever else your favorite IDE might provide you (e.g. XDebug/DBGp integration) to inspect state during these key functions to get to the bottom of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [File (Field) Paths](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_paths)?

If yes, this is the module which is disturbing the thumbnail generation in the form.

Comment: Nope I'm not using https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_paths..

Comment: are you private or public?

Comment: I m uploading to public!

Comment: If it is sure that image is in public:// it is fine (on the other hand you should use Imagecache External). Two questions: is it only with IE? Could you provide the error (is it 404)? And one idea: disable clean URL and check again.

Answer (score 1):

Same happened to me while I was on maintenance mode, Images styles was not generated, images not being loaded (404), once I turned maintenance off, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this several times, either because I have left a kint function uncommented(seems to cause Ajax to fail to display derivatives), or one of my custom modules(or settings.php) has a blank line before the opening php tag. Worth checking.